# Web2py, authenticating two types of profile

Tags: authentication, web2py

In one application I need to create two types of accounts, let's say users and tutors.
Each of them should be able to register/login/... user/tutor account defined by different tables in db.

e.g.

`[app]/user/register` should provide a form with fields: `username, email, password, hobby`
`[app]/tutor/register` should provide a form with fields: `username, email, pass, name, surname, telephone`

Web2py auth service allows using `auth_user` table which can be customized. Is there a way to use two tables separately according to controller in one application?

Field `auth.settings.table_user` contains reference for auth_table but I probably shouldn't use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Auth system isn't designed to work this way. Instead, it would probably be better to put all the fields for both user types in the single `auth_user` table and then selectively set the `readable` and `writable` attributes of the fields to `True` or `False` depending on the context.

In the model file defining Auth:

```
user_extra_fields = [Field('hobby'), ...]
tutor_extra_fields = [Field('telephone', ...]

auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = (
    [Field('user_type', requires=IS_IN_SET(['User', 'Tutor']))] +
    user_extra_fields + tutor_extra_fields)
```

In the controller that manages the Auth functions:

```
def user():
    if request.args(0) in ['register', 'profile']:
        hidden_fields = (user_extra_fields if request.args(1) == 'tutor'
                         else tutor_extra_fields)
        for field in hidden_fields:
            field.readable = field.writable = False
    return dict(form=auth())
```